# JS - StreamSaver downlad does not start

Tags: javascript

I download data from API in chunks decrypt it and than pass to ReadableStream.
But after last chunk, the file is not downloaded.
I work with axios and [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js)

Code:

Above in the code I declare:

```
this.filestream = streamSaver.createWriteStream('sample.jpg');
this.writer = await this.filestream.getWriter();
```

```
let readableStream;
readableStream = new ReadableStream({
    start(ctrl) {
        const nextChunk = async () => {
            let fileDataResponse = await that.$api.post(
                'endpoint', {
                    file_id: UUID,
                    chunk_index: index
                }, {
                    headers: {
                       ...
                    }
                }
            );
            done =
                fileDataResponse.data.length <=
                fileDataResponse.data.current_index;
            if (fileDataResponse.data.data) {
                let data = await that.decryptData(fileDataResponse.data.data);
                ctrl.enqueue(data);
            }
            if (!done) {
                index += 1;
                nextChunk();
            } else {
                ctrl.close();
            }
        };
        nextChunk();
    }
});
const reader = readableStream.getReader();
const close = () => {
    that.writer.close();
};
const pump = () =>
    reader.read().then((res) => {
        if (!res.done) {
            that.writer.write(res.value).then(pump);
        } else {
            close();
        }
    });
pump();
```

Where could be my error here?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: It's unclear to me how `index` and `done` are scoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was the res.value is not an Int8Array